# Add bold text and line break into Laravel Notification Email

Tags: php, html, laravel, notifications

Laravel 5.6

I'm attempting to send a Laravel Notification via email.  I want to make make some of the text bold, and put in line breaks, without a whole new paragraph that the `line($text)` method brings. So I have tried this in the notification class.  I have also tried using the `\n` string for new line.

```
return (new MailMessage)
->subject('Booking Confirmed - Please Read')
->greeting('Hello ' . $this->booking->user->first_name . ',')
->line('Thank you for booking. Here are your booking details:')
->line($this->booking->provider->providerType->name . '<br>' .
    $date . '<br>' .
    $this->booking->start_at . '<br>' .
    $this->booking->address_1 . '<br>' .
    $this->booking->address_2 . '<br>' .
    $this->booking->address_3 . '<br>' .
    $this->booking->city . '<br>' .
    $this->booking->postcode . '<br>' .
    '£' . $this->booking->price
)
->line('<strong>Need to cancel?</strong><br>' .
    'Don\'t forget to contact the provider on the details above if you need to cancel or reschedule. 
    They won\'t mind, as long as you tell them.'
)
->line('<strong>Payment</strong><br>' .
    'Pay the Service provider direct as you normally would. This keeps things simple and costs down.'
)
->line('<strong>FAQ\'s</strong><br>' .
    'Please click here for more information'
)
->line('<strong>Don\'t forget to leave feedback after!</strong><br>' .
    'Help build your relationship with your Service Providers by leaving feedback'
)
->line('We hope to see you again soon!')
```

I have tried with and without publishing the blade templates via the `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` command and then updating `{{$line}}` to `{!! $line !!}}` with no joy.  Can't figure it out.

It prints put like this in mailtrap
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out, incase anyone else out there is as dumb as me.
I think there are 2 reasons why this was broken.  @DouwedeHaan suggested I use double quotes instead of single when using `\n` which didn't do much but combined with the next part I think did the trick.

The blade template that renders the html is in markdown. I hadn't figured this out.  The layout of it is specific, and I had accidentally broken it after I published it by removing some lines and formatting the file with indents which broke everything.

I deleted the file, re-published the template updated all instanced of `{{$line}}` to `{!! $line !!}` ensuring to leave the rest of the file as is, updated my notification to use double quotes and stuck with `<br/>` and `<strong></strong>` tags and now it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: great! it works. thank you!

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps you have done your job as the question is so old. But I would like to share an easy way to write an HTML tag on the Laravel mail template.

First of all, you are required to import
`use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;`

```
->line(new HtmlString('Last date: <strong>' . $this->due_date . '</strong>'))
```

The `HtmlString` class enable you to write HTML tag on mail body.
It would be helpful for someone who is looking for this type of solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Laravel it was introduced in, but you can use Markdown in `MailMessage`, so `HtmlString` is not necessary if simple formatting is all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use normal line breaks with single quotes

```
'This will create a
new line'
```

or use `\n` with double quotes

```
"This will also create a \n new line"
```

[More info here](https://phppot.com/php/php-line-breaks/)

Comment: No that didn't seem to work.  It stripped out the \n tags and still put it all on one line.  thats for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for a solution here, this is what works great:

```
...

->line(new HtmlString('<hr/>'))
->line(new HtmlString('<strong>Name: </strong>' . $this->contact->first_name))

...
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to update the notifications view indeed so you are on the right track.

Basically after publishing the notification package's resources doing so:

$ php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications

All you need to do is open resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php and replace the occurrences of {{ $line }} with {!! $line !!}.

This is just telling Blade not to escape the tags.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You clearly haven't read my question.  I did that already.  I know what {!! !!} does.